too many request issue, API image upload
I copied the code from the docs imgur tutorial:
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.imgur.com/3/image");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Client-ID {apiKey}");

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\EUGENE\\Desktop\\HEAL.png")), "image", "C:\\Users\\EUGENE\\Desktop\\HEAL.png" },
            { new StringContent("image"), "type" },
            { new StringContent("Simple upload"), "title" },
            { new StringContent("This is a simple image upload in Imgur"), "description" }
        };
        request.Content = content;

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }


But when I start I get code: 429, response: too many requests.
What could be the problem?
At the beginning, I thought that there was an error in creating the API (I did something wrong), but it turned out that it returns this in any case.
I have not violated the limits before, I tried this for the first time, so I don’t think that this problem is my fault.
I get the same error in postman.

429 does imply you violated limits. Some (bad) APIs use this to indicate that there's a billing issue.

and yet I will say that I did not violate the API limit, there are ~4 people on my router, of course, tomorrow I will try to do this on some server

Right but if you think that's not the reason, thats still what the server emits. So if you suspect that the server emits this for an unusual reason, nobody on stack overflow can speculate why. We can only speculate what it typically is, which is: Too many requests.

very strange, I checked it on a friend’s PC and on a vds, same problem

There's no reason to assume that the limit is ip-based.
